# How to change Tab Order on Dynamics 365 entity forms?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have several forms for various entities which would greatly benefit from having the Tab Order for the fields changed from Top to Bottom to Left to Right. There are many forum posts with the same JavaScript function on this subject, but I do not understand how the code changes the order.

I have implemented the `TabOrderLefttoRight` function shown on many different sites. The actual tab order has not changed after adding this code. In the meantime, I have gone with the "supported" route, creating many sections with two columns in them. This works, but takes up a lot of space between the sections, as well as adds borders in between fields that are related, so shouldn't have borders in between them. My client would prefer the fields to be in the same section. Is there something wrong with this function?

This is the code that is shown on multiple websites, given as a solution for this problem. Wouldn't the Tab Order stay the same with this code, the tab index would just be increased by 1000?

```
function TabOrderLeftToRight() {

    for (var i = 0; i < Xrm.Page.ui.controls.getLength() ; i++) {

        var control = Xrm.Page.getControl(i);
        window.console.log(control);
        var element = document.getElementById(control.getName());
        window.console.log(element);

        if (element.tabIndex && element.tabIndex != "0") {
            if (element.className == 'ms-crm-Hidden-NoBehavior')
                continue;
            if (element.tagName == 'A') {
                if (element.className != 'ms-crm-InlineTabHeaderText')
                    continue;
            }
            element.tabIndex = 1000 + (i * 10);
        }
    }
}
```

The tab order should be Left to Right, Top to Bottom after adding this code into the form's OnLoad event, but it does not change. the tab order stays Top to Bottom, Left to Right.

Comment: if these are the new CRM Unified Interface forms, `Xrm.Page` has been deprecated

Comment: It is a Dynamics 365 instance, I am not sure how to tell if the Unified Interface forms or not. I have done other customizations using Xrm.Page without issue though.